# Find implemented types from Generic interface in c#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

```
public class AccountCreatedEvent : EventBase{}   

 public class AccountHandler : IEventHandler<AccountCreatedEvent>
    {
        public void Handle(AccountCreatedEvent event)
        {
        }
    }
```

This is a handler class and I want to get this class with c# code. I want to get list of implemented classes from IEventHandler type.

```
public class Account
{
    public void OnAccountCreated(EventBase accountCreatedEvent)
    {            
        var handler = typeof(IEventHandler<>);            
        var events = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => handler .IsAssignableFrom(p) && handler.IsGenericType);

    }
}
```

But `var events` is returning

```
 {Name = "IEventHandler`1" FullName = "Project1.IEventHandler`1"}
```

Comment: What is `denormalizer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Praveen, but using how the generic interfaces are handled

```
Type interfaceType = typeof(IEventHandler<>);
Assembly mscorlib = typeof(System.Int32).Assembly;
Assembly system = typeof(System.Uri).Assembly;
Assembly systemcore = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).Assembly;

var events = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    // We skip three common assemblies of Microsoft
    .Where(x => x != mscorlib && x != system && x != systemcore).ToArray();
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => p.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == interfaceType)).ToArray();
```

Note that to speedup the thing a little, I'm skipping three common assemblies of Microsoft. Skipping all the MS assemblies is a little more complex (it could be done through the PublicKeyToken, but I don't think it is a very-very-good idea... A PublicKeyToken is 64bits, and it isn't really guaranteed to be unique... and retrieving the full PublicKey of an assembly is probably a pain)

Answer (score -1):

The below code will fetch a list of all types that implement the interface IEventHandler

```
var events = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => p.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.Name == handler.Name && i.Namespace == handler.Namespace));
```

We are basically checking if all interfaces implemented by a class match the handler interface name. You can make it more restrictive to check for other parameters like the namespace, just in case you want to search across assemblies.

Comment: Comparing by Name only is not enough, since you can have types with the same name in different namespaces.